# Python cmd module - adding new headers

Tags: python, python-module

Python's 'cmd' module has the ability to provide with headers.

for example, documented commands can get this header:
"Documented commands (type help ):"

and undocumented commands can get this header:
"Undocumented commands:"

I know the text can be changed by providing doc_header and undoc_header custom values, but I could not understand if additional headers/sections can be created

below is an example of what I want to achieve, where newcmd1 & newcmd1 are.

```
python cmd_arguments.py
(Cmd) help

Documented commands (type help ):
========================================
greet

Undocumented commands:
======================
EOF  help

New section of commands:
========================
newcmd1 newcmd2
```

Comment: I don't think so, why do you want that?

Comment: because I want to divide the commands into sections. for example: network commands, system commands, etc.